# lxml.html treats two similar inputs differently?

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am seeing some unexpected output while using `lxml.html`.

```
import lxml.html as LH

xmlspec = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>"

a = LH.fromstring(xmlspec + "<html><body><p>Body</p></body></html>")
b = LH.fromstring(xmlspec + "<html><meta /><body><p>Body</p></body></html>")

print a # says element p while I would have expected html
print b # says element html which is expected
```

Can someone explain why is this happening? Everything works fine when you remove the `xml` specification! Is there a right way to deal with this?

Comment: I think you found your error. Originally you had the `<meta />` outside the `<html>`

Comment: @JavierBuzzi, good observation. I corrected that. I still get the same error.

Comment: Hum. Yup you're right, still googling, but if you swap the import from `html` / to `etree` and dont change anything else: It works. BUT im like a dog with a bone, and i like you, want to understand the WHY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what little 20+ mins of research have led me to is that:

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><html><body><p>Body</p></body></html>`

is NOT valid HTML, it's valid XML.

Technically speaking,

`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?><html><meta /><body><p>Body</p></body</html>`

Is also NOT valid HTML, but lxml is forgiving it. A more acceptable compliant version would be to add `<head><meta /></head>` right after `<html>` and that is better but still not great (for it to be a valid HTML it needs to have a `<title>` inside `<head>` and of course, a different doctype).

References:

https://validator.w3.org

https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: Thanks, buddy. I will see how to handle this!